# apex:detail Render related list only

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to show list of all cases related to the account on case page in console.

E.g. If case 000001 is related to Mr. ABC then on right panel of console of case 000001 I would like to show all the cases related to Mr. ABC
I am using

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:detail subject="{!Case.AccountId}" inlineEdit="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

However, this shows entire Accounts page, is there a way to just show Cases and nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apex:detail` renders the entire detail area based on the record's current layout (determined by the record type/profile matrix). If you want just a related list, use `apex:relatedList`. Here's a trivial copy-paste example:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:relatedList list="Cases" subject="{!Case.AccountId}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Surprisingly this was not working before when I tried and now it is working.